# Java Server page

Tags: jstl

I have implemented the if / else tag in JSTL like following. But its not working. If condition not checking.

```
<c:choose>
    <core:if ${capital.nextCapital()} eq ${request.capital}>
         <p> Yes. The capital of ${capital.nextState()} is ${capital.nextCapital()} </p>
     </core:if>
    <c:otherwise>
         <p>No. The capital of ${capital.nextState()} is ${capital.nextCapital()} </p>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not valid syntax at all.

1. the standard prefix is `c`, not `core`
2. inside `c:choose`, you can use `c:when` and `c:otherwise`. Not `c:if`.
3. the boolean condition must be inside a `test` attribute:
4. Attributes must be surrounded by quotes:

   ```
   <c:when test="...">
   ```
5. The whole boolean EL expression must be inside ${}:

   ```
   <c:when test="${ ... }">
   ```

So the end result should be

```
<c:when test="${capital.nextCapital() eq request.capital}"> ... </c:when>
```

I suggest you re-read your book or tutorial about custom tags and the JSTL.

Comment: You need to refine your diagnostic. "not working" doesn't mean anything concrete. What happens? What is printed if you add ${capital.nextCapital()} to know what its value is? And when you add ${request.capital}?